# open a putty window and run ssh commands - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh

I am new to python. I need to login to a server daily (Desktop -> 1.32 -> 0.20 -> 3.26). For this I need to open putty and using ssh connection i am logging in. To do all this I want to write a script using python.

By using google I thought subprocess.Popen will do that. But Its not working fine.

1st trail:

```
import subprocess
pid = subprocess.Popen("putty.exe user@xxx.xx.x.32 -pw password").pid
```

Its working fine (Opening window logging into .32). But cant able to give input. I came to know that to give input for the same process we need to use pipes.

2nd trail:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
p = Popen("putty.exe user@xxx.xx.x.32 -pw password", stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)    
grep_stdout = p.communicate(input=b'ssh xx.xx.x.20\n')[0]
print(grep_stdout.decode())
```

by using this i cant login for the first server also. After logging in to all servers I need the terminal as alive. how to do this???

**Edit**

I need to do this in a new putty window. After logging in dont close the window. I have some manual work to do.

Answer (score 2):

There is a SSHv2 protocol implementation for python: http://www.paramiko.org/. You can easily install it with pip:

```
pip install paramiko
```

Then you can create ssh client, connect to your host and execute commands:

```
import paramiko
ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect('hostname', username='login', password='pwd')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command('command')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use paramiko library python
Establish a SSH connection using -

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname,username, password)
```

Check the status if connection is alive using -

```
status =  ssh.get_transport().is_active()
#returns True if connection is alive/active
```

ssh.exec_command() is basically a single session. Use exec_command(command1;command2) to execute multiple commands in one session

Also, you can use this to execute multiple commands in single session

```
channel = ssh.invoke_shell()
stdin = channel.makefile('wb')
stdout = channel.makefile('rb')
stdin.write('''
  Command 1
  Command 2
  ''')

print stdout.read()
```

Comment: I need to pop a new window (putty) and have to login. After login is complete to all server (Desktop -> 1.32 -> 0.20 -> 3.26) don't close the putty window (I have some manual work to check).

Answer (score 2):

use powershell to call putty in order to open a new window

```
from subprocess import Popen
Popen("powershell putty.exe user@host -pw mypassword")
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a bat file on windows, which references putty and putty session-specific info. This bat file can run by itself on windows. To call from python, I used the subprocess.run() -- python 3.5+.

Example of bat file named putty.bat:

`start c:\app\PuTTy\putty.exe -load 192.168.1.230-node1-logs -l <logon user> -pw <logon user password for putty session>`

Breaking down the bat file:

1. It begins with window's command "start".
2. c:\app\PuTTy\putty.exe --> is the putty directory on Windows containing putty.exe.
3. -load --> tells putty to load a putty profile. The profile is the name you see on the putty client, under "Saved Sessions".
4. 192.168.1.230-node1-logs --> my putty session specific profile.
5. -l for logon --> followed by the putty logon user.
6. -pw is the logon password --> followed by the putty logon password.
   That concludes the contents of "putty.bat".

From within python, is used the subprocess.run() command.

Example:

```
import subprocess
...
...
                try:

                    process = subprocess.run(["putty.bat"], check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

                    print(process.stdout)

                except Exception as e:

                    print("subprocess call error in open putty command")
                    
                    print(str(e))
```

I hope you find this helpful